# registerFont() from node-canvas not parsing font on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, fonts, google-cloud-functions, node-modules, node-canvas

I am currently working on generating an image with `node-canvas` via Firebase Cloud Functions, then sending it as an email attachment with `nodemailer`.

The requirement of the image is that I need to input some string onto a template with a specific font.

So on Firebase Cloud Functions, here is what I did:

```js
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
      let tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tnr.ttf');
      functions.logger.log('tempFilePath is', tempFilePath);

      bucket.file('tnr.ttf').download({destination: tempFilePath});
      functions.logger.log('Font downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);

      registerFont(path.resolve(tempFilePath), {family: 'tnr'});
      functions.logger.log('Font registered successfully');
  }
}
```

I have already verified repeatedly that the file `'tnr.ttf'` exists on my project cloud and can successfully be loaded to that temp path.

At the `registerFont` function however, Firebase would always throw this error, no matter which font file I use:

```
Error: Could not parse font file
    at registerFont (/workspace/node_modules/canvas/index.js:48:17)
```

Could there possibly be a problem with how Firebase handles this package or function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the font before it has finished downloading. By the time you realize the problem, open up a terminal and confirm that it's actually present, the download has finished.

What you need to do is wait for either the Promise returned by `download(...)` to resolve or attach a callback to the `download()` method. Then after it's finished downloading, you can register the font.

```js
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, (corsErr) => {
    if (corsErr) {
      // this is rare, but still possible.
      functions.logger.error('Request rejected by CORS: ', corsErr);
      res.status(412).send('Rejected by CORS'); // 412 FAILED PRECONDITION
      return;
    }

    let tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tnr.ttf');
    functions.logger.log('tempFilePath is ', tempFilePath);

    bucket.file('tnr.ttf').download(
      {destination: tempFilePath},
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          functions.logger.error('Failed to download font to local system: ', err);
          res.status(422).send('Failed to register font'); // 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
          return;
        }

        functions.logger.log('Font downloaded locally to ', tempFilePath);

        registerFont(path.resolve(tempFilePath), {family: 'tnr'});
        functions.logger.log('Font registered successfully');

        res.send('Registered font successfully');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Don't forget to properly handle errors and terminate requests properly.
- The same function invocation may be invoked again, consider setting a "I already downloaded that" flag somewhere. In a "worst-case scenario", you may end up with 100s of the same font file.
- Make sure to execute the `registerFont` method where you will be using it. You can't have separate `/registerFonts` and `/drawWithFont` endpoints, as you aren't guaranteed to be talking to the same function instance you were a moment ago.